# Return to the page before the update form page in Yii framework

Tags: php, html, yii

I have an update page in Yii and updates a users login schedule at `<baseurl>/admin/manage/updateSchedule/userid/1`

At the end of the form I have the usual `<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Save'); ?>`

The update action redirects back to the same page to display a flash-success message next to the Save button for 3 seconds.

I also want to have a "Return to Previous Page" link on the page.
If I use

`<a href="<?php Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer;?>">Return to previous page</a>`

then after a save, it will just redirect to the same page, as this is the page I came from.
If I use

`<a href="<?php Yii::app()->request->returnUrl;?>">Return to previous page</a>`

, it takes me back to the yii app index page.

How can I get back to the page before the update login schedule page? e.g. `<baseurl>/admin/manage/`

Answer (score 0):

How about `<a href="<?= Yii::app()->createUrl("admin/manage")?>">Return to previous page</a>`?

Or you could use CHtml: `<?php echo CHtml::link("Return to previous page", array('admin/manage')); ?>`

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#link-detail

Comment: Both these work. I settled for a button instead: `<?php echo CHtml::button('Go Back', array('submit' => array('index'))); ?>` This works for static links, but not if this page was referred from any other page than manage/index.